# Hierarchy in Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I need some directions on how to think about the following problem.

Consider this Cypher question:

```
MATCH (n:news)<-[r:COMMENT*1..]-(m)-[:POSTED]-(o:user) 
WHERE ID(n) = 54041
RETURN m,r,o
```

It gives this graph:

[image: graph]

And this result returned:

[image: data]

As you can see, the `newscomment` with body "*Heh...*" is a `newscomment` to the node with the body "*Eyyy!*" which is a `newscomment` to a `news` node.

So far, so good. But, on the site I want to show the news and below that I want to list all newscomments in a hierarchical way, much like on this [reddit example](http://www.reddit.com/r/steampunk/comments/1ud4rb/i_retextured_sunflowers_in_minecraft_into/).

As it is now, there's no way to tell whether a news comment is a comment on the news or another news comment.

Should I save the parent nodes `id` as a `parent` attribute on each node? Can I somehow get the order of steps away `[r:COMMENT*1..]` is and that way figure out where to place the comment in the UI?

How would you solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think maybe you're looking for a simple subquery here to find the parent:

```
MATCH (n:news)<-[r:COMMENT*1..]-(m)-[:POSTED]-(o:user) 
WHERE ID(n) = 54041
WITH m,r,o
MATCH (m)-[:COMMENT]->(parent)
RETURN m, r, o, parent
```

Would this work?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems like it would work as I want it to, but it would be more efficient to save a parent property on each newscomment node, right?

Comment: Compared to the varlength path in the first part of the query, the single traversal done by the second part of the query is pretty trivial. Sure, you might gain some milliseconds (although I would test before assuming that) by adding another property, but you lose some bytes.